# How to use MPLS VPN connection between branch offices, to connect LAN hosts that exist at different office branches?

Tags: networking, vpn, mpls

Our ISP has provided  us with a MPLS VPN connection to enable us communicate our other 3 branch offices with our head office. They provided us with WAN addresses for each dedicated router at our offices. Each of this routers are connected to a LAN for the internal networks at the office. We are currently able to ping between each offices using WAN addresses , however we are still unable to ping between the remote LAN networks . We need to setup a  host PC as a server in our head office to host a web portal, to be accessed by hosts in the remote LANs that are connected to the VPN modems. What things could be missing that are not enabling us ping operation between hosts in the LANs??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you seek professional help from a network consultant.

Assuming you own and configure the routers connecting the LAN to the WAN, you need to enable routing on them so they know which WAN address to use as a next-hop IP address for the LAN networks on the other sites.

```
Site A                                  Site B
172.16.0.0/16 - ROUTER - WAN - ROUTER - 172.17.0.0/16
```

On the router connecting Site A to the WAN, you will need a route for 172.17.0.0/16 pointing to the WAN address of Site B's router. You can either do this using static routing or, preferably using dynamic routing protocols (e.g. OSPF or BGP).

How to do this will depend on your equipment, your expertise, your network design, etc etc. Best to consult a professional to come take a look on-site.

**edit:**

You can consider the MPLS network to be a huge virtual router with each of your locations connecting to one interface of it. This means that you will have to configure routing on your side towards the MPLS network for each remote network, but the MPLS provider also needs to learn which network lives at which branch office. With OSPF or BGP this is done automatically, with static routes your service provider will need to add those static routes manually. Consult with them on the options you might have (static, OSPF, or most likely BGP).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feed back! I will check on the routing  myself. I was just confused as to how the MPLS should function with respect to our LAN networks, since I can tracert to a host on remote LANs, however ping to a hosts on remote  LAN networks only works for a while after a successful trace to that particular remote host is completed . Then the ping command to this remote host comes back to its usual request timed out error.

Comment: You can consider the MPLS network to be a huge virtual router with each of your locations connecting to one interface of it. I've edited and expanded my answer.